# Responsive Multi level drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a multi-level responsive drop down menu.

[This link opens a pdf that holds the pictorial description that I am trying to code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwhJGJMt7Wx2bjE2cHc3SzRmTHc)

page1 in pdf - depicts multi level view

page2 in pdf depicts the first level of drop downs. A B and C are drop down menus

page3 in pdf depicts the complete view when drop-down C and all its children drop-down menus are clicked till the end of hierarchy i.e., till level4

1. Each level - 1, 2, 3 and 4 have to be aligned horizontally center and vertically middle. The entire design needs to be responsive.
2. At each level, on clicking a drop-down list item, the next level has to be shown.
3. Any level should disappear or collapse on mouse-out.

I tried various approaches, using the bootstrap framework. Each of the approaches ended up with some limitations. Tried lots of debugging, taking clues from google search and forums. All went in vain.

Can some one suggest what could be the best approach? 
Can this be achieved with a combination of  html5, css3, jquery and bootstrap framework alone?
Does this bring in a need of any other technology to be deployed?

Comment: You can go though this link https://codepen.io/gaurav22/pen/MEwEwy. It can help you better.

Comment: Thank you, Gaurav. The link has given me some help.